# C++ Loop Error "Exited With Non-Zero Status" for Random Password Generator

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, compiler-errors, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to learn loops and conditionals in c++ so i decided to write a program that generates a random password for the user. For some reason the code works maybe 1/5 times, but the rest of the time it just gives me "Exited With Non-Zero Status".
Thanks,
Evin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    using namespace std::this_thread;
    using namespace std::chrono;
//  Vars
    string lett;
    int input;
    string password("");
    string lettArray [] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f", "g", "h", "i", "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

//  Prompt
    cout << "How long would you like your password to be?";
    cin >> input;
//  Loop
    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        struct timespec ts;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
        srand((time_t)ts.tv_nsec);
        int random = (rand() % 26 + 1);
        lett = lettArray[random];
        password = password + lett;
        sleep_for(milliseconds(10));
        cout << "." << endl;
        if (random == 0 )
            break;
    }
//  Output
    cout << password << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's the problem, but remove the +1 in the assignment to random. You want numbers in the range of 0 to 25, not 1 to 26.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel I guess this is an attempt to increase entropy (which is unlikely to gain a lot here ...)

Comment: Actually there are a few cases where you re-call `srand`. This isn't one of them

Comment: The example code on the linked page calls srand twice, so no it is fine it call it more than once.

Comment: A few ills: No function calls are tested for failure. For example, `clock_gettime` could have failed resulting in an invalid `ts` @WayneTanner  has allready pegged one big but of undefined behaviour that could easily trigger a crash: there is no `lettArray[26]`. Recommend running the program under GDB to see exactly where the crash is and then inspect the variables around the crash site.

Comment: Back on-ish topic, if using `chrono`, [`steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) should deliver as good monotonic time as `clock_gettime`. And [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) will deliver better and usually easier to manage results than `rand`/`srand`.

Comment: @user4581301 well I was just pointing out the bad use of srand. If he's still learning loop and conditionals not sure that was intentional. Indeed that wasn't an answer, just a comment. Then I'll remove them, don't want the comment section go into a mess because of me sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this program fails at random (pun intended) is that you are using C-arrays, and you got the index range wrong.

C-arrays, such as lettArray, do not check whether the array bounds are violated. In your example, if you run this program, `lettArray[26]` will give you a segmentation fault because there is no `string` element in that memory address. The C-array does not check the bounds, so it can be difficult to know what went wrong. This can get especially tricky in complicated programs because if something happens to be in that memory address you can get a nonsensical result.

A better implementation would be using `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    // You don't need these two lines
    //using namespace std::this_thread;
    //using namespace std::chrono;

    //  Vars
    string lett;
    int input;
    string password("");

    // Vector index range: 0-25
    vector<string> lettArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f", "g", "h", "i", "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

    // You only need to initialise the seed once.
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    srand((time_t)ts.tv_nsec);

//  Prompt
    cout << "How long would you like your password to be?";
    cin >> input;

//  Loop
    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        int random = (rand() % 26 ); // You get results between 0-25
        // Using lettArray.at(26) will result in a crash with a clear 
        // message that bounds are violated  
        lett = lettArray.at(random); 
        password = password + lett;
        cout << "." << endl;

       // Don't see a reason for this if statement
       // if (random == 0 ){
       //     continue;
       //}
    }
//  Output
    cout << password << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also moved the random seed outside the loop (you only need this once), and there is also no reason to have the 10 millisecond pause. You will see that your results are properly randomised regardless.

Comment: Thank you so much! :), I am new to C++ and am coming over from Java.